# How to specify a domain name while verifying google id token

Tags: node.js, google-signin, google-workspace

I am writing a function to verify a Google id token. I'm strictly following [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) but I'm stuck on one last step. The token must be from a particular G-suite domain. The code snippet below is from the documentation but I don't know how to interpret it. Do I replace `hd` with `mydomain.com`? How do I specify my domain name?

```
// If request specified a G Suite domain:
// const domain = payload['hd'];
```

**Kindly let me know if there is any additional detail I omitted in this question. There is no issue with my current code but I'll just add a little snippet here for context:**

```
const token = getToken(event);
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);

async function verify() {

  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: token,
    audience: CLIENT_ID
  });

  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];

  }

  // const domain = payload['hd'];

  verify().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: 'hd' the key for the domain value in the payload ... if it's set, then <code>domain = payload['hd']</code> will give you the user's domain as a string and you can check that it matches yourdomain.com ... does that help?

Comment: I understand way better now! Thank you very much! Basically, I have to do the eventual if-check by myself after getting the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'hd' is the key for the domain value in the payload ... if it's set, then `domain = payload['hd']` will give you the user's domain as a string and you can check that it matches yourdomain.com